# Gray code in partial files where suggestions are presented

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and it grays some of my variables in my codes that weren't grayed in Visual Studio 2017.

For example, if I write "Variable = null" (assuming the specific Variable is already declared and has a value inserted inside) then it grays it and suggests to delete that line.

These suggestions are destructing me, and annoy my eyes as the color of the codes keep on changing.

How can I disable those specific suggestions (and not disabling suggestions totally) or at least not allowing it to become light gray, changing its color to black or not letting it effect the previous color.

Comment: Why not follow the suggestions and remove the unneeded code?

Comment: @juharr equaling to null might be needed, it ensures that a variable isn't taking memory anymore after resetting it, but besides that, it happens in more situations, for example : declaring a variable and using it only inside a certain if condition, i can declare it inside the if condition but i want all my declarations to be at the beginning of the code so i won't get confused. and during the time i write the code it just destructs me.

Comment: *"it ensures that a variable isn't taking memory anymore"* - NOT!

Comment: Did you read the hint it gives you? This should not be a 'distraction' (let alone a destruction) to you but a valueable insight into the state of your code!

Comment: @matanjustme It sounds like your real problem is that you're trying to still code like you're using C instead of C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I disable those specific suggestions

You can disable the suggestion (not just the formatting, but the actual suggestion itself) by clicking the lightbulb icon in the gutter of the editor window ([image: Visual Studio lightbulb]), and choosing the "Configure or Suppress issues" menu item in the popup menu.

For the issue you're asking about, "Remove unused members", that's `IDE0051`. Select the "Suppress" menu item for that issue, and choose from one of the three options. For keeping the code file itself clean, using the "in Supression File" is best. It will track that particular line of code, but in a separate file, out of the way of the code itself.

Comment: that didn't solve the issue directly, since i don't mind the errors themselves as long as they're not destructing me from coding, however, it's the best solution I've encountered so far therefore I've accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

**Color Theme Designer plugin** can solve the problem.

The light gray colour of text can be changed to a colour of choice using this free plugin.

Color Theme Designer can be downloaded from

> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.ColorThemeDesigner

Comment: but what's the category and the specific setting that does that? the plugin helps me to create a new theme, but there're hundreds of options and how will i check each one, logically i'd need to create tons of themes just to check.

Comment: after checking the options of the plugin i couldn't find anything that matches in it (tried to apply and change all of the gray colors and it couldn't change it, though it changed other stuff).

Comment: _Color Theme Designer plugin can solve the problem._ There is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a solution, but I've found something that will be useful for me, perhaps a bug in visual studio 2019 basic themes.

The theme Blue (Extra Contrast) color of the text that's supposed to be grayed - isn't getting grayed, infect it's effected only by the setting of User Members - Locals (and perhaps other user member types, but the colors depend on them and the text isn't getting grayed).